# Outputting UTF-8 with PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, utf-8, simplexml

I'm trying to parse an XML file generated from Wordpress' export function. I've grabbed the text from the  block but when I echo the text it gets malformed, into ASCII I think.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset: UTF-8;");

$source = file_get_contents("blog.wordpress.2013-10-31.xml");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);

$items =  $xml->channel->item;

foreach($items as $item) {
    $namepsaces = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
    $content = $item->children($namepsaces['content']);
    if($content != '') {
        echo '#' . $item->title . "#\n";
        echo $content->encoded;
        echo "\n\n\n";
    }
}
```

So `As the BBC’s` would become `As the BBCâ€™s`. Anyway I can stop this?

Edit: I've appended echo '“Test”'; to just after the header and I'm seeing â€œTestâ€ in my browser, so this doesn't appear to be a SimpleXML issue.

Comment: AFAIK Wordpress export function does not export valid XML and it perhaps does not take care of character and transfer encodings properly as well. Please ensure the XML is valid before assuming the error would be in the code you've got in question.

Comment: And it's not US-ASCII it's more like some Latin-1 or Windows-1252 - but encoded as UTF-8, displayed as such and again encoded as UTF-8 to be displayed like you show in your question. - Most likely just http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

Comment: Its fixed now, I think it was a problem with PHP on my Mac. I had PHP 5.5.5 installed though homebrew but the plist file in LaunchAgents was still pointing at 5.5.1. I don't know, I've sorted that out, rebooted and voila, eveyrthing looks like it should.

Answer (score 0):

As UTF-8 ’ (0xE2 0x80 0x99) is WINDOWS-1252 â € ™ and that is exactly what you describe, it seems that you load UTF-8 encoded strings as WINDOWS-1252.

The output of SimpleXML when you read from elements or attributes is always UTF-8 encoded, therefore about that part I see no problem with your code.

So it's more likely that the XML file has the wrong encoding hinted. Fix that and you should be fine (as you have not shown that file, it's hard to say what exactly needs to be changed and why the encoding got mixed-up in the first place, perhaps some transfer issue).

You perhaps need to re-encode the XML file before you send it to the parser. If so, [`XMLRecoder`](https://gist.github.com/hakre/5194634) *might* be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a colon here: `charset: UTF-8`

The correct code is

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML file starts with 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`